# How can I define a generic struct in Rust without one of the fields being of the generic type?

Tags: rust

I have the following problem (it is simplified a bit).

There is a trait which supplies a set of functions which do not use `self`:

```
pub trait ImageFormat {
    fn write(data: Vec<[u8; 3]>, path: &str, ...) -> io::Result<()>;
    ...
}
```

with several implementations.

There also is a struct which uses functions from that trait:

```
pub struct Images<T: ImageFormat> {
    path: String,
    ...
}

impl<T> Images<T> where T: ImageFormat {
    pub fn setup(path: &str, ...) -> Images<T> {
        Images {
            path: String::from(path),
            ...
        }
    }

    fn write(&mut self, data: Vec<[u8; 3]>, ...) -> io::Result<()> {
        T::write(data, &self.path[..], ...)
    }
    ...
}
```

This does not compile, because the struct does not have a field of type T.
It works if I do this, but it feels like a hack:

```
pub struct Images<T: ImageFormat> {
    _image_format: Option<T>,
    path: String,
    ...
}

impl<T> Images<T> where T: ImageFormat {
    pub fn setup(path: &str, ...) -> Images<T> {
        Images {
            _image_format: None,
            path: String::from(path),
            ...
        }
    }
...
}
```

Is there any idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: why don't just write "struct Images" if struct doesn't need `T` ? Please describe more what you want. If you really want to "force" it, you can use [phamtom data](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html), but I feel that you should not use it in your case.

Comment: The struct does not need T, but the methods like write on Images do need it. All I need in practice is the type, as these functions do not use self. Phantom data seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: That doesn't add information, I still think you use the bad tool for your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html) can be used "to mark things that "act like" they own a T".

So, you could write:

```
pub struct Images<T: ImageFormat> {
    path: String,
    phantom: PhantomData<T>, // mark that Image "acts like" it owns a T
}
```

In initialization, you simply provide a `PhantomData` for the respective field:

```
Images {
    path: ...
    phantom: PhantomData,
}
```

As mentioned by others, you may be better off without the type parameter in the first place, but I have had cases where they seem perfectly reasonable to me (e.g. if `T` provides functions that do not take a `self`).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly my case. T provides functions that do not take self.

Comment: "if T provides functions that do not take a self", and ? just add the generic to the impl not the struct, I don't understand the use case. On the contrary I think that typical bad use case of phantom data.

Comment: The actual use case (https://github.com/myszon/raytracer/tree/master/src/format) is a bit more complex. Instances of `Images` are not used directly, but as trait objects to choose behaviour in runtime. So if generic was just added to the `impl`, then the compiler would not be able to chose the correct variant of `write` when called from a trait object.